# How to make foam / bubbles in liquid

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I'm trying to make some bubbles and foam in liquid. Something like in the image below.

[image]

I'm thinking about particles, but I don't know how to make bubbles of different sizes. I also don't know how to make the bigger bubbles on the top and the smaller ones on the bottom.

Maybe some smart shader? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I found something similar that you want to achieved. May be this tutorial can help you to achieve that bubbles. Follow this tutorial, and after that, do some modification about variant of bubbles. https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-beer-blender/# Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this would be possible to do with Boolean modifiers. Just create a sphere, deform it with modifiers so it looks more like a blob, then repeat it in a bubbly pattern within the fluid object. Once you've got all the bubbles where you want them, select them all and join them with `CTRL` + `J`. Then select the fluid, go to modifiers and add a Boolean modifier. Then select the bubbles under object. and apply.